# Package a custom extension

Tags: magento2, module, custom-extension

Can anybody help me to provide the complete process of making my custom module install able and update able using composer.

I am using my custom bit bucket repository to upload my code base of extension.

Please provide complete steps

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Before commit create tag

```
        git tag 0.2.1
```

Step 2: Add and commit and push you're changes

```
        git add .
        git commit -m "message"
        git push branch
```

Step 3:  Push your tag also

```
        git push origin <tag>
```

Step 4 : Create account in https://packagist.org/

Step 5 :  Get the packagist token from profile section

Step 6: Go to git repository and settings section webhooks section setup the token key

Please refere this url https://github.com/CurrencyCloud/currencycloud-php/wiki/Publishing-package-to-Packagist